# Unable to load XML on Internet Explorer with jQuery (locally)

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, parsing

I have trouble loading an xml file stored on my local network... (you could say... local HDD... it doesn't matter I guess).
I have the piece of code that you find everywhere online:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "data\raportfile.xml",
   dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
   error: function(data){
      alert('ma-sa de treaba');
},
   success: function(data){
     var xml;
     if (typeof data == "string") {
       xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
       xml.async = false;
       xml.loadXML(data);
     } else {
       xml = data;
     }
     // Returned data available in object "xml"
   }
 });
```

But I don't know why... I get the error message... that this stuff doesn't work...
Are there any ways besides this one? Is there something I do wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path `data\raportfile.xml` looks like a filesystem path. Your file needs to be accessible over http.

Put the file somewhere in the site root, and address it using forward slashes ie `/path/to/file.xml`

Comment: hahahaha ...damn!! You saved me... I tried every method possible and impossible and nothing worked.. and just a little slash solved it! thanks!